# How to compare Point objects in a set?

Tags: java, point

Im doing an exercise where I have these points with (x,y) stored in a set and I have these set stored in a HashMap with the type of point as the key `HashMap<String,Set<Point>>.`
Now what im trying to do is compare the points in a set to find 3 or more points that are vertically or horizontally aligned and are next to each other. so if point A(2,3), point B(2,4) and point C(2,5) would satisfy this. I would like to put these points that passed the test in another list. Any ideas how to do this? any help is appreciated

Ok going with the nested loop Stephen suggested

```
for(Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<Point>> e : grid.entrySet()){
   if (e.getValue().size() > 3){
   for(Point p1 : e.getValue()){
      for(Point p2 : e.getValue()){
         if (neighborCheck(p1,p2) == true){
            System.out.println(p1 + " " + p2);
         }
      }
   }
}

public boolean neighborCheck (Point p1, Point p2){
        boolean neighbor = false;
        if((p1.getX()==p2.getX()+1 && p1.getY()==p2.getY()) || 
           (p1.getX()==p2.getX()-1 && p1.getY()==p2.getY()) ||
           (p1.getX()==p2.getX() && p1.getY()==p2.getY()+1) ||
           (p1.getX()==p2.getX() && p1.getY()==p2.getY()-1)) {
            neighbor = true;
        }
        return neighbor;
    }
```

outputs:

> java.awt.Point[x=3,y=4] java.awt.Point[x=4,y=4]
>   java.awt.Point[x=4,y=4] java.awt.Point[x=3,y=4]
>   java.awt.Point[x=0,y=4] java.awt.Point[x=1,y=4]
>   java.awt.Point[x=1,y=4] java.awt.Point[x=0,y=4]
>   java.awt.Point[x=3,y=2] java.awt.Point[x=4,y=2]
>   java.awt.Point[x=4,y=1] java.awt.Point[x=4,y=2]
>   java.awt.Point[x=4,y=2] java.awt.Point[x=3,y=2]
>   java.awt.Point[x=4,y=2] java.awt.Point[x=4,y=1]

It works for 2 points but this definitely isn't the solution because to check for three points I would need to nest 3 loops and so on. i cant just keep nesting more loops because i wont know how may points there will be aligned and I need to compare 3 or more, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in the following way :

```
    Map<String, Set<Point>> mapSets = new HashMap<String, Set<Point>>();
    Set<Point> p1 = new HashSet<Point>();
    p1.add(new Point(2, 3));
    p1.add(new Point(2, 4));
    p1.add(new Point(2, 5));
    p1.add(new Point(3, 1));
    p1.add(new Point(4, 1));
    p1.add(new Point(5, 1));

    mapSets.put("p1", p1);

    Map<Double, List<Point>> horMap = new HashMap<Double, List<Point>>();
    Map<Double, List<Point>> verMap = new HashMap<Double, List<Point>>();

    for ( Point p : p1 )
    {
      List<Point> presList = horMap.get(p.getX());
      if ( presList == null )
      {
        presList = new ArrayList<Point>();
        presList.add(p);
      }
      else
      {
        presList.add(p);
      }
      horMap.put(p.getX(), presList);
    }

    for ( Point p : p1 )
    {
      List<Point> presList = verMap.get(p.getY());
      if ( presList == null )
      {
        presList = new ArrayList<Point>();
        presList.add(p);
      }
      else
      {
        presList.add(p);
      }
      verMap.put(p.getY(), presList);
    }

    // boolean hNe = checkHorNeighbor(horMap);
    // boolean vNe = checkVerNeighbor(verMap);

    for ( Entry<Double, List<Point>> point : horMap.entrySet() )
    {
      if ( point.getValue().size() >= 3 )
      {
        Collections.sort(point.getValue(), new Comparator<Point>()
        {
          @Override
          public int compare(Point o1, Point o2)
          {
            return Double.valueOf(o1.getY()).compareTo(Double.valueOf(o2.getY()));
          }
        });

        int count = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < point.getValue().size(); i++ )
        {
          if ( point.getValue().get(i).getY() + 1 == point.getValue().get(i +
                                                                          1).getY() )
          {
            count++;
          }
          if ( count >= 2 )
          {
            System.out.println("Found horizontal pair");
            count = 0;
            break;
          }
        }

      }
    }
  }
```

There can be a similar run for getting the vertical straight lines.

Another way of doing it is to do the following. It should be much faster and clean.

```
private static boolean checkVerNeighbor(Map<Double, List<Point>> verMap)
  {

    for ( List<Point> ps : verMap.values() )
    {
      NavigableSet<Point> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Point>(new Comparator<Point>()
      {
        @Override
        public int compare(Point o1, Point o2)
        {
          return Double.valueOf(o1.getX()).compareTo(Double.valueOf(o2.getX()));
        }
      });

      sortedSet.addAll(ps);

      for ( Point p : sortedSet )
      {
        Set<Point> triplets = sortedSet.subSet(p, true,
                                               new Point(Double.valueOf(p.getX() + 2).intValue(), Double.valueOf(p.getY())
                                                                                                        .intValue()), true);
        if ( triplets.size() >= 3 )
        {
          System.out.println("Found Triplets + " + p);
          return true;

        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the hashmap . Take one set and compare its (x,y) with each of other sets by creating another iterator to the hashmap . If your condition satisfies , just store it in another list .